# Best way to port MFC COM Server to Managed code

Tags: c#, .net, c++, com, mfc

I am working on an application suite comprising of multiple Automation servers written using MFC and this is legacy code. These apps inter communicate via COM interfaces and other events. Most of these apps provide multiple form views with various input controls to capture information. I was wondering what would be the best way to migrate these applications to managed code one app at a time. Any advice...
We work in native code, but porting the code base to managed world is my personal idea because I can see a lot of functionality that can be achieved in a better way if the code is written as managed code.

Thanks,
Byte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write new parts of server using [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI). It looks like a less painful option.

Comment: I thought about that. But the existing app is a COM  server and if I am not wrong, .NET automation server is difficult to host as an Out of Process server. Also I would prefer converting the UI to .NET - WinForm, haven't thought about WPF yet.
I would prefer if you can share any experiences you have with porting such apps in the past and blunders to avoid...